# cygwin make chktex command not found

Tags: cygwin

When I'm trying to make chktex-1.7.4 with cygwin I get the following output:

```
$ make install
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/latex ChkTeX.tex
make: /cygdrive/c/Program: Command not found
Makefile:265: recipe for target 'ChkTeX.dvi' failed
make: *** [ChkTeX.dvi] Error 127
```

I also modified the fstab file. It contains

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
C:/Program\ Files   /c/Program\ Files ntfs binary 0 0
```

Can anybody help me to get the `make install` to work?

Comment: Apparently, chktex is unable to cope with spaces in paths. Solutions as always include a) not using spaces in paths, b) fixing everything to handle spaces correctly.

Comment: @DavidMacek, fixing means modify source-code or are there other possibilities?

Comment: I meant modifying the source code. It's possible the problem is isolated to just one place in the Makefile, which wouldn't be so hard to fix even if you're not big on programming. There's always the option of trying to get the chktex maintainers to fix it.

Comment: Has anyone addressed/solved this issue yet?

Comment: @FredrikP I installed my miktex on `c:\miktex` to get sure no whitespaces are in the path, so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution, without changing position of Miktex installation. If `latex`and `dvips` are binaries on your `%PATH%`, than you can compile modifying generated `Makefile` (lines 49 and 50)

```
$ nano Makefile
[...]
# LATEX=/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64//latex
# DVIPS=/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64//dvips 
LATEX=latex
DVIPS=dvips
```

and rerun `make install`. **Please be sure that those binaries are in your path or this will not work!**